# inline-block relative margin-top affect all sibling divs

Tags: css

I have the following code, after apply `margin-top` to one of the divs eg. `#two`, all divs have `margin-top: 20px`.

Does relative `margin-top` apply to all siblings if one of divs defined?

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#two {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <div class='item'>One</div>
  <div class='item' id='two'>Two</div>
  <div class='item'>Three</div>
  <div class='item'>Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because all `.item` has a default `vertical-align: baseline` (due to `display: inline-block`). You can add `vertical-align: top` to either `#two` or `.item`, depending on what you want to achieve:

```css
.item
{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#two
{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **Flex** and make it simple.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#two {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
</div>
```